# Search bar not showing properly in actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar-compat

i am using actionbarcompat v7 for the first time; there is a problem with action search while I:

1.) move device with landscape mode the search and it's sentences cut-off from top side,
2.) Want to edittext white color drawable. I already tried

```
final AutoCompleteTextView searchPlate = (AutoCompleteTextView)mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_holo_light);
```

I also tried changing the theme, like

```
<item name="searchViewTextField">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
```

But it did not work.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your layout file code ?

Comment: i did't make layout file for actionbar it is only implement using take just menu and (programatically) action bar code.